# modify routing in url manager in yii

Tags: yii

I have different modules folder like `user`, `cms`, `importcsv` etc.

Here, I want to modify the URL so that all module names are replaced with the string `admin` and remain same for the controller, action and hide parameter

For example:

- `user/profile/view` corresponds to `admin/profile/view`
- `cms/site/setting` corresponds to `admin/site/setting`

I have tried it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    'admin/<controller:\w+>' => 'user/<controller>',
),
```

Comment: If are all admin, why dont you create a single module?

Comment: you are right but I have already build modules separately, so I want to browse with admin url name for all modules using url manager

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple controllers in each module?  If not, maybe you should just use a single admin module.  However, if you really need these things to be separate modules, then maybe you need that last route to look like:

```
'admin/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'user/<controller>/<action>',
```